# Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I am trying to establish a socket connection between my Android app and my local Apache server. However, when the code is run, I get the following error in Logcat: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied). Here is my client-side code (The error occurs in the line `socket = new DatagramSocket(this.serverPort, ip);`:

```
public Memcached(String target, int serverPort, int attackDuration) throws MalformedURLException {
        targetURL = new URL("http://" + target);
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
        this.attackDuration = attackDuration * 1000;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName(targetURL.toExternalForm().replace("http://", ""));
            Log.d(TAG, ip.getHostAddress());

        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.out.println("Unknown host");
            ipAddressAbleToBeFound = false;
        }
        if (ipAddressAbleToBeFound) {
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(this.serverPort, ip);
            }
            catch(SocketException se) {
                System.out.println("Unable to send request, is it down already??");
                se.printStackTrace();
                socketAbleToBeCreated = false;
            }
            if (socketAbleToBeCreated) {
                while(System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + attackDuration) {
                    byte[] buffer = {10,23,12,31,43,32,24};

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, ip, this.serverPort);
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                    }
                    catch(IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("I/O error occurred");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest file has the proper permissions I believe. My `ip` is set to the my local IP address, which is how my local Apache server gets accessed. My `this.serverPort` is set to `80`, which is less than 1024. I've read that the issue might be because I am trying to connect to a port less than 1024. However, when I set `this.serverPort` to 1024, I get the following error: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address). So I am not sure what to try. Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information! Thanks!

Comment: What is used value of `ip`?

Comment: The value of ```ip``` is my local ip address

Comment: Please tell the value i asked.

Comment: Does `String target` already contain this address?

Comment: Yes it does, I think I may have found a work around for this issue though that I am about to post

Comment: Actually, I took down that workaround post because it wasn't really a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got around this by doing `socket = new DatagramSocket();` as opposed to `socket = new DatagramSocket(this.serverPort, ip);`. It looks like you don't need to specify port and InetAddress in the DatagramSocket, you just need to do so in the DatagramPacket.